# How to extract a 14 digit number from a cell?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a query regarding the below cell data where i have different information available in a single cell:

"237 2002 45990181000189 ROBERT BOSCH L"

and i only need to extract the 14 digit number in the adjacent cell out of it.

can someone give me a formula to be able to extract this information?

and if possible can someone give me a "if" condition because the number of digits may vary ex: sometimes 14 sometimes 8.

Thanking you in advance!
Shekar

Comment: Is it always the **third** number in the cell ??

Comment: No, It may vary! sometimes the number comes at last

Comment: If the data that you are looking for is not in a standard format it will be very hard to have a formula get what you are looking for. Is there a way to format the data so that it is in a standard order?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text to columns`with space as delimiter.

You can use this formula but excel cell doesn't hold a value exceeding a specific value, check this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

This formula will give best result to 18 digit.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A1,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$25),1))*ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a formula to do this. Try selecting the column containing these cells, then go to the `data` menu, and click `Text to Columns`. When the dialog window comes up press `delimited`, then press next, and tick `Space`, then press `next` and `finish`.

This will split your cells into the separate components.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an array formula:

```
=CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999*( ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,999))),IF(LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999*( ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,999)))=14,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999*( ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,999)),""),""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

You have to have Office 365 Excel to use it.

You can Change the `14` in the formula to any number length you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
=MID(R75,FIND(" ",R75,FIND(" ",R75,1)+1),FIND(" ",R75,FIND(" ",R75,FIND(" ",R75,FIND(" ",R75,FIND(" ",R75,1)+1)+FIND(" ",R75,1))))-(FIND(" ",R75,FIND(" ",R75,FIND(" ",R75,1)+1))))
```

This is assuming that the value is in cell R75. Obviously, you will have to update it to wherever the data is.

This formula is looking for the " "(spaces). It is taking the `mid` of the cell R75 starting at the second space and using a length of the 3rd space minus the 2nd space. In the case of the example above it ends up being `mid(R75,9,(24-9))` or `mid(R75,9,15)`

Comment: @ShekarYelimela Glad i could help!